# Mysterious behavior from flat_map

Tags: rust, flatmap

The result of

```
println!("{:?}", (1..4).flat_map(|x| x*2..x*3).collect::<Vec<usize>>())
```

Is `[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, while I would expect `[2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,8,9,10,11,12]`.

Why do I get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `flat_map` but with [`std::ops::Range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.Range.html), which is defined to be "inclusively below and exclusively above". That is, in a `1..4`-range the highest value will be 3, not 4. What you are looking for is [`std::ops::RangeInclusive`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.RangeInclusive.html), which you'll have to use two times in your code:

```
fn main() {
    // Notice that
    assert!(!(1..4).contains(&4));
    // but
    assert!((1..=4).contains(&4));

    assert_eq!(
        (1..=4).flat_map(|x| x * 2..=x * 3).collect::<Vec<usize>>(),
        vec![2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
    )
}
```